# how to create a samba share to the /home directory

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtual-machines, mappeddrive

So i'm a developer, not a dev ops person so i'm out of my element. Thanks in advance for your patience.

I'm running windows 7 and set up a vmware player to run an ubuntu 12 virtual machine.  I've installed samba so I can map a drive to the website that is running on the VM.  Basically, I want to edit the files for the site on my windows machine while they live on the VM. Pretty straightforward.

Here's the problem.  When I map my network drive, I can access \\local\brad (local being my server name) but not \local\www.  Problem is, the files live in \www which is a sibling to \brad.  so more clearly:

```
\home\brad\stuff-i-don't-care-about
\home\www\what-i-want-to-map-to
```

Can anyone explain why that is / offer possible solutions?

EDIT: As @Duke clarified below, What I really want is create a samba share for / or /home directories on my windows machine. Thanks for helping me state my goal better

Comment: don't be a tool and downvote without a comment.  If you don't like my question at least be courteous enough to give me some constructive feedback along with the downvote...given that this is my second question EVER on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mounting something else than yout root partition to / is NOT a good idea, and probably won't even work.

But there is a workaround: [chroot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot) allows you to change the root a program sees, even makes it possible to "switch" to a completely different linux installation.

Ubuntu help page to the topic is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot)

EDIT: Duke got me down the path on this.  My problem was in the samba config file:

```
[bobby]
  path = /home/bobby
  available = yes
  valid users = bobby
  read only = no
  browsable = yes
  public = yes
  writable = yespath = /home/bobby
```

I needed to give my user access to the /home dir like so

```
[bobby]
  path = /home
  available = yes
  valid users = bobby
  read only = no
  browsable = yes
  public = yes
  writable = yespath = /home
```

Worked like a champ...Thanks @duke

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, just noticed I got it the wrong way.

Comment: its not a good idea even though its just a development box virtual machine?

Comment: I believe I missunderstood you the first time. What you really want is create a samba share for / or /home?

Comment: yes...which ever of those two will let me work on the files in /home/www from my windows machine